# Java JNI Programming - java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, compiler-optimization

I created a java application to access C functions via JNI interface. When accessing the function i got the below error

> "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:"

I found 4 to 5 links for this error in stackoverflow and unfortunately i am not blessed to get answer to solve my error. So i searched google with the phrases "Netbeans + mingw + java + jni". And there i found the answer to solve the error. That is, adding the below line in the compiler option (in Netbeans) solved the above highlighted error.

[> **"-shared -m32 -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias"**](http://www.javaxt.com/Tutorials/Netbeans/How_to_Create_a_JNI_with_Netbeans)

So Is there any of the way to find the missing of this compiler option when one receive this error (or) Should one learn all the compiler option with C Language for various OS (Android, Windows) & Compilers (Mingw, Cygwin)?

**Additional Info :**
*Environment :*

```
OS : Windows 8.1 64 bit     
Java jdk1.8.0_51 (32 bit)      
Mingw 32 bit     
Netbeans runs using 32 bit Java
```

*Java Code :*

```
package avajjni;
public class AvajJNI {
    static{
        System.load("D:\\cpro\\c_jni_library\\dist\\Debug\\MinGW_32-Windows\\libc_jni_library.dll");
    }
    public native void fnDisplayData();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AvajJNI obj = new AvajJNI();
        obj.fnDisplayData();
    }
}
```

*C Code (.c)*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "avajjni_AvajJNI.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_avajjni_AvajJNI_fnDisplayData
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj){
    printf("JNI Method Called\n");
}
```

*Actual Error When not using above said compiler options*

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: avajjni.AvajJNI.fnDisplayData()V
    at avajjni.AvajJNI.fnDisplayData(Native Method)
    at avajjni.AvajJNI.main(AvajJNI.java:9)
```

Comment: XY problem. There is nothing in that link that suggests that omitting those compiler options will cause this error. I suggest you post the *actual* error you are receiving, and the relevant code, and stop jumping to conclusions.

Comment: @EJP thanks. After some time i will post the actual code.

Comment: @EJP, the actual error and the code posted in the section "Additional Info"

Comment: Well you have to use at least `-shared` and choose the right architecture, but surely this is obvious? You shouldn't be thinking about testing for compiler options at runtime. Your unit tests should pick this problem up.